# How to tell sequelize which database to use when creating a transaction?

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am working on an API using NestJS along with Sequelize. I'm going crazy trying to do multiple queries to a database using transactions. Problem is that the mentioned database is the second one that I have defined for Sequelize in my App's Module and EVERY transaction that I create with Sequelize always takes the first connection to a database, which is the default one.

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: connection_1_dbserver,
      port: connection_1_port,
      username: connection_1_username,
      password: connection_1_pass,
      database: connection_1_dbname,
      models: [...],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      name: connection_2_NAME,
      host: connection_2_dbserver,
      port: connection_2_port,
      username: connection_2_username,
      password: connection_2_pass,
      database: connection_2_dbname,
      models: [...],
      synchronize: false,
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have tried creating the transaction using directly the connection to the second database (connection_2_NAME) and that's why I inject it into the service. So the service is looking like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExportService {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection(connection_2_NAME)
    private readonly connection_2_name_ref,
    private sequelize: Sequelize,
  ) {}

public async export(id: number): Promise<{ code: number }> {
    let result = { code: 1 };
    ...
            try {
              return this.connection_2_NAME.transaction(transaction => {
                // First query
                return this.removeCurrData(
                  id,
                  transaction,
                )
                  .then(() => {
                    // Second query
                    return this.insertNewData(newData, id, transaction);
                  })
                  .then(exportResult => {
                    if (exportResult) {
                      result.code = 3;
                    } else result.code = 2;
                    return result;
                  });
              });
            } catch (error) {
              result.code = 2;
              return result;
            }
          } else result.code = 2;
    ...
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Connection_2_NAME.transaction() gives me a transaction but it commits after the first query in the chain is successfully executed. How to query the second sequelize DB connection in the config using transactions?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**SOLUTION:**

I was supposed to inject the Sequelize instance for the given connection. But instead, I was creating a new reference to that connection to use it later when creating the transaction. For this reason, the Sequelize instance injected was related to the default connection and not the one I needed to use. So, always make sure you have the correct instance injection...

```
constructor(
    @InjectConnection(connection_2_NAME)
    private sequelize: Sequelize,
  ) {}
```

After that, you can work with the transaction as usual:

```
return this.sequelize.transaction(async t => {...}); // t is the transaction to execute queries using models managed by the connection_2_NAME connection.
```

I'm still learning but hope this helps someone. Happy coding ;)

Comment: This would be more straightforward to read using `async/await`. Can you include the code for `removeCurrData()` and `insertNewData()`?

Comment: My bad! @doublesharp I already realized where my mistake was. The problem is that when I was injecting the connection, for some reason instead of injecting the Sequelize instance for the given connection, I was creating a new reference to it. The correct way:  `constructor(
    @InjectConnection(connection_2_NAME)
    private sequelize: Sequelize,
  ) {}` Then created the transaction as usual: `return this.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {..});` Thank you